# Can access API in console app, but not ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: c#, api, socketexception

I've written some C# code to access the Google Distance Matrix API.Initially I put my code into a console application within visual studio 2019. My code is below.

```
string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=newyork&destinations=boston&key=MyKey";
        Uri myUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

        //HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responsereader = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(responsereader)));
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables["element"].Rows[0]["status"].ToString() == "OK")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + ds.Tables["duration"].Rows[0]["text"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Distance: " + ds.Tables["distance"].Rows[0]["text"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

This code works as expected with the API. Then, I copied the code into an ASP.Net MVC application. However, when I run the MVC app, I get an error on line:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

[image]

Could someone please help resolve?

Thank you.

Comment: Port 443 is TLS/SSL secure mode of https.  Check your browser option to see if TLS/SSL is enabled.  Maybe you need to use Port 585?  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request in the API with the c# request.  Make the headers in c# look exactly like the headers in the working API.

Comment: Have you add your domain to  `Google Distance Matrix API` from `Google Admin Console` ?

Comment: @jdweng Hi, thanks for your help. I can hit the API URL in my browser, so I'm assuming TLS/ SSL is not a problem. What is even more strange now is, I've downloaded Fiddler, and when I run Fiddler in the background and also run my MVC app which hits the API URL, my code works. However, when I don't have Fiddler running in the background, and then try to run my MVC app, the code falls over again at `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`

Comment: Fiddler should have nothing to do with the error it should be transparent.  I suspect running the API first and then your application works.  The API may set up a cookie.  You need to compare the 1st request in work and non work and compare the headers.  What sometimes work is set http to 1.0 (instead of 1.1) :  request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;